# String and array, php

Tags: php

I'm developing my first website and when I try to submit my form all I get back in my error_log is this:

```
[04-Oct-2020 11:24:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  mail() expects parameter 5 to be
  string, array given in /home/public_html/printform.php on line 13
```

I've tried adjusting different things and I've also tried to google about string and array but to be honest I don't really understand.. This is what my php file looks like:

```php
<?php
    $to = $_POST['myemailadress'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    
    $headers=array(
        'From: $email_addressn',
        );
        
    $sent = mail($to, $name, $email, $size, $headers);
    
?>
```

Comment: headers is not array

Comment: convert your array ($headers) into string with the help of implode function, then pass it

Comment: Please look PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

Header parameter is not array it's string.

```
     <?php
        $to = $_POST['myemailadress'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $size = $_POST['size'];

        $headers= "From: $email" . "\r\n" .
                  "CC: $email";
            
        $sent = mail($to, $name, $email, $size, $headers);

    ?>
```

Comment: I tried that one now and it came back:

PHP Warning:  mail(): headers parameter must be string or array in /home/public_html/printform.php on line 11 

So I guess it's still something wrong with it but I will try to read about it with the links from the comments. Thank you for your help!

Comment: its working here , i tested it locally